# How can I render partial in show.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial-views, rails-activerecord

I have these two models in my Ruby on Rails application - Artist and Song. They are associated as follows:

> class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> has_many :songs
>
> attr_accessible  :artist_name

and

> class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> belongs_to :artist
>
> attr_accessible :title, :track_URL, :artist_id

I have this code in views/artist/show.html.erb:

```
<%=  render 'artist_song'  %>

<table>
    <% @artist.songs.each do |song| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= song.title %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

The partial Im trying to render(_artist_song.html.erb) in the same view looks like this:

```
<table>
  <% @artist = Artist.all %>
  <% @artist.each do |artist| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to artist.artist_name, artist %></td>
      </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The way it is suppose to work is when I click on an artist shown trough the partial, the code below the partial has to show me all the songs that belongs to the particular artist.
Both the partial and the code in the table tag are working individually. But when I put them together, it looks like there is a conflict between them and the server is showing me this No Method Error:

```
NoMethodError in Artists#show

Showing C:/Sites/OML/app/views/artists/show.html.erb where line #9 raised:

undefined method `songs' for #<Array:0x5fe1418>
Extracted source (around line #9):

6: 
7: 
8: <table>
9:     <% @artist.songs.each do |song| %>
10:         <tr>
11:           <td><%= song.title %></td>
12:         </tr>
Rails.root: C:/Sites/OML

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/artists/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_artists_show_html_erb__950110288_54062208'
app/controllers/artists_controller.rb:21:in `show'
```

I couldn`t find a solution. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: add @artist = Artist.all  in controller for show method

Comment: How are you setting `@artist`? Is it a ActiveRecord model?

Comment: Artist is an ActiveRecord model yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a partial. You need to render the partial inside the `artist` loop:

**show.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <% @artists = Artist.all %>
  <% @artists.each do |artist| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link_to artist.artist_name, artist %></td>
    </tr>
    <%= render :partial => 'artist_song', :artist => artist %>
   <% end %>
</table>
```

This way, you are passing the current `artist` object to inside the partial, so there you can do:

**artist_song.html.erb**

```
<% artist.songs.each do |song| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= song.title %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```